# proof of some normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know how to proof that the subgroups $n\mathbb{Z}$, $GL^+(n,\mathbb{R})$, $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, and $SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ as a subgroup of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$, are normal subgroups. Thanks!

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Here's a widely-applicable hint, besides checking by hand: if $f : G \to H$ is a group morphism, then $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Let $Q \in SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $A \in O(2,\mathbb{R})$, for example we can let $$
Q=
\left(
 \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
   \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
 \end{matrix}
\right), \ \
A=
\left(
 \begin{matrix}
   0 & -1\\
   1 & 0
 \end{matrix}
\right)
$$. Then we can know that $$
AQA^{-1}=\left(
 \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
   \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
 \end{matrix}
\right)
$$. It is obvious that $AQA^{-1} \in SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, so that $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the normal subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: As show in the upper comment, I can proof $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$  is a normal subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$. But what if $n \neq 2$, how can we proof that this  conclusion suited to $\forall n \in Z^{+}$?

Comment: How is $n{\bf Z}$ even a subgroup of $O(n,{\bf R})$?

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $n{\bf Z}$ is a subgroup of a lot of groups, Zhenyu. Sometimes it's a normal subgroup, sometimes it isn't. It's not enough to name a subgroup; you have to say what the intended group is, if your question is to make any sense.

Comment: I am the beginner of this filed, as far as I know is that $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, could you please tell me that is there a group which is different from $\mathbb{Z}$ let $n\mathbb{Z}$ be its subgroup? Thank you very much!

Comment: If $n=rs$ is composite, then $n{\bf Z}$ is a subgroup of $r{\bf Z}$. $n{\bf Z}$ is a subgroup of the rational numbers, and of the group of polynomials with integer coefficients. Given any group $G$, $n{\bf Z}$ can be identified with the subgroup $n{\bf Z}\times1$ of the group $n{\bf Z}\times G$. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! You answer is so helpful for me!@GerryMyerson

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** note that since $\det AB = \det A\det B$, we have

$$
\det ABA^{-1} = \det B.
$$

Thus any set of the form $$\{x \in \mathsf{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}): \det x \in  S\}$$ with $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is invariant under conjugation by any subgroup of $\mathsf{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

As for subgroups of integers, have you tried *anything*? Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal. In particular, you can check it by hand.

Comment: Can I proof as follows that $\forall n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. So that we can get $$q \times np \times q^{-1}=np \subseteq n\mathbb{Z}$$. Above all, we can get $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.